# Collecting multiple rows into a column using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a heavily linked data model stored in neo4j. The data is along these lines:

```
Component -> Part (only 1)
         \-> Fastener (only 1)
```

Subsequently any node with label Part or Fastener may have any number of links to other nodes (but never back to a Component).

What I'm trying to do is return all the Components with a Part column, Fastener column, and one column for that Part's connections (say as an array of dictionaries) and also one column for that Fastener's connections.

Currently I have a very basic query that "works" but yields multiple rows of the same Component whereby one row consists of unique Part or Fastener connections. The query is:

```
MATCH (c:Component)-[:MADE_WITH]->(p:Part), (c)-[:MADE_WITH]->(f:Fastener), (p)-[p_m:MATERIAL]->(p_m_unk), (f)-[f_m:MATERIAL]->(f_m_unk)
RETURN c.name, p, f, p_m_unk, p_m, f_m_unk, f_m
```

After some reading it seems like the COLLECT function will do part of what I need, but if I do this:

```
MATCH (c:Component)-[:MADE_WITH]->(p:Part), (c)-[:MADE_WITH]->(f:Fastener), (p)-[p_m:MATERIAL]->(p_m_unk), (f)-[f_m:MATERIAL]->(f_m_unk)
RETURN c.name, p, f, COLLECT([p_m_unk, p_m]), COLLECT([f_m_unk, f_m])
```

This doesn't quite do what I want since the column with less data (either `p_m_unk` or `f_m_unk`) will have duplicated rows.

How do I get this query to return one row for each `c.name` containing all Parts `p`, Fasteners `f`, and all their respective first level connections?

(I've changed the actual structure and name of labels to be something more generic than my use case, but the data model and query are still the same.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, the problem I think is that you're trying to do all the matching at the start, which is generating a cartesian product and eventually creating duplicates in your collections. You'll want to break up your matches, collecting your data separately (so output from each step is a single row per component) to avoid the cartesian product.

```
// you can still match against part and fastener together to start
MATCH (c:Component)-[:MADE_WITH]->(p:Part), (c)-[:MADE_WITH]->(f:Fastener) 
WITH c, p, f
// now match on part connections and collect
MATCH (p)-[:MATERIAL]->(p_m_unk)
WITH c, p, f, COLLECT(p_m_unk) as partConnections
// now match on fastener connections and collect
MATCH (f)-[:MATERIAL]->(f_m_unk)
// could do a return here if we wanted to
WITH c, p, f, partConnections, COLLECT(f_m_unk) as fastenerConnections
RETURN c.name, p, f, partConnections, fastenerConnections
```

Comment: Thank you for the help InverseFalcon! Your solution as well as the one from cybersam both work well for me.

Answer (score 2):

If it is OK to return 2 rows per `Component`, one for `Part` and one for `Fastener`, the query can be as simple as this:

```
MATCH (c:Component)-[:MADE_WITH]->(pf)-[m:MATERIAL]->(unk)
RETURN c.name, LABELS(pf)[0] AS label, pf, COLLECT({m:m, unk:unk}) AS materials;
```

*The query assumes that the `Part` and `Fastener` nodes have no other labels.*

Here is a sample result:

```
╒══════╤════════╤═════════════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│c.name│label   │pf           │materials                     │
╞══════╪════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│Froomb│Fastener│{name: Batz} │[{m: {name: MFlidget}, unk: {n│
│      │        │             │ame: Flidget}}, {m: {name: MCo│
│      │        │             │rb}, unk: {name: Corb}}]      │
├──────┼────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│Froomb│Part    │{name: Bleet}│[{m: {name: MSignaft}, unk: {n│
│      │        │             │ame: Signaft}}, {m: {name: MTr│
│      │        │             │em}, unk: {name: Trem}}, {m: {│
│      │        │             │name: MMert}, unk: {name: Mert│
│      │        │             │}}]                           │
└──────┴────────┴─────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

However, if you really the result for each `Component` on a single row, this query will do that:

```
MATCH (c:Component)-[:MADE_WITH]->(pf)-[m:MATERIAL]->(unk)
WITH c.name AS name, pf, COLLECT(m) AS ms, COLLECT(unk) AS unks
ORDER BY LABELS(pf)[0] DESC
WITH name, COLLECT({pf: pf, ms:ms, unks:unks}) AS data
RETURN name, (data[0]).pf AS p, (data[1]).pf AS f, (data[0]).ms AS p_ms, (data[0]).unks AS p_m_unks, (data[1]).ms AS f_ms, (data[1]).unks AS f_m_unks;
```

*The `ORDER BY` clause sorts in descending order by the label of the `pf` node so that, in the `data` collection, the `Part` data has index 0 and the `Fastener` data has index 1.*

Here is the what the result would look like (with the same sample data):

```
╒══════╤═════════════╤════════════╤══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│name  │p            │f           │p_ms                          │p_m_unks                      │f_ms                          │f_m_unks                      │
╞══════╪═════════════╪════════════╪══════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│Froomb│{name: Bleet}│{name: Batz}│[{name: MSignaft}, {name: MTre│[{name: Signaft}, {name: Trem}│[{name: MFlidget}, {name: MCor│[{name: Flidget}, {name: Corb}│
│      │             │            │m}, {name: MMert}]            │, {name: Mert}]               │b}]                           │]                             │
└──────┴─────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you InverseFalcon and cybersam for your replies!! Both solutions provided work very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DISTINCT` modifier inside the `COLLECT` function calls.

```
RETURN c.name, p, f, COLLECT(DISTINCT [p_m_unk, p_m]), COLLECT(DISTINCT [f_m_unk, f_m])
```

That will remove duplicates from whichever list is longer.